# Multiple instances of perl script running in parallel via JButton action listener

Tags: java, multithreading, perl

I'm executing a Perl script via `"Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:/script.pl")"`

as part of a Jbutton action listener. I would like to be able to click the button twice and get two instances of the same Perl script running. The script is reading in a text file so it acts a little differently depending on the text file the second time it is started but in general the script does the same thing.

I've tried to combat this by wrapping the runtime command in a new thread and executing a `".run()"` on it each time the button is pressed but this only seems to interrupt the first instance and start the new one. There seems to be no way to execute two of the same Perl script in parallel. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

```
ActionListener edit = new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

      class GetThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
          try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Perl/bin/perl5.16.3.exe C:/Perl/get.pl", null, new File("C:/Perl"));
          } catch (IOException e1) {
            exceptionLog(e1);
          }
        }
      }
   GetThread get = new GetThread();
   get.run();
   }
}
```

Comment: show the code, please

Comment: added the code of the action listener, not sure if that is what you want to see or something else, if so just let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html says

Every Java application has a single instance of class Runtime that allows the application to interface with the environment in which the application is running. The current runtime can be obtained from the getRuntime method.

It may be blocking on your call.

Comment: That makes sense as my application has several buttons that all start different perl scripts (in separate threads) but all accessing the same runtime environment, therefore not allowing me to click 2 of the buttons and get the desired functionality. Any idea on how I could make it work in this way? Would using process builder help at all?

Comment: I don't know whether you could background the calls?  Then there would not be a block, but there are serious repercussions to consider, such as too many forked processes and not knowing then they end.

Comment: Thank you, I probably should've thought to use that since I use some background processes elsewhere in the application. The Perl scripts I'm executing only last about a minute, don't do anything heavy duty and I'm not particularly interested in when they finish, as long as they run and don't interrupt one another its fine. Thanks again.